# swift TVOS ScrollView can't scroll

Tags: swift, uiscrollview, tvos

I am having problems with a scroll view in TVOS i have a picture that is 4000x2400 that i want to be in side a scroll view but i can't get the scroll view's content to be big enough so i can only se 1/4 of the picture even when i scroll the lithe i can i am not sure what i am doing wrong.

i created the scrollview in the storybord and set the constrains so that it fills the screen out then put the picture in side the scroll view and forced the size of the picture to be 4000x2400 with is the pictures size.
If any now what i am doing wrong or now how to do it right i would be very happy.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you tried to solve it with TVML? In TVML there is an element called background, you can also try to use it.

Comment: i thinks some of my problem was that contentSize was not set but now it scrolls when you go from one button to another but it goes to far in sted af centering the button it goes to it goes so far that the button is not even on the screen anymore.